# not able to get rid of SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found WARNING

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, slf4j, lombok

I am using `Spring boot 3.0.5` with `Lombok`. No matter what dependency I add of `slf4j` I am not able to get rid of following warning..

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
```

I have tried and followed this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652836/slf4j-found-slf4j-api-dependency-but-no-providers-were-found)

But all in vain.

Following is my `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pep</groupId>
    <artifactId>pepMech</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pepMech</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As a result I am not able `Run as> maven-clean` and `maven-install` and thus not able to generate jar file in my target directory. Please suggest what should I do. I want to get rid of this warning and get ready with my jar.

Comment: Start off by trying to add [this as a normal dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.4.11)

Comment: Same issue. It has stuck so badly.

Comment: You specify NOP (which basically means no logging) and you wonder why you get a message stating you don't get logging? There are also conflicting jars on the classpath (as the message tells you). Run a `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is on the classpath.)

Comment: Firstly, do you get the same errors if you run mvn in the console, outside your IDE? It seems you should have 2 providers with this pom: `LogbackServiceProvider` and `NOPServiceProvider`.